# Error Undefined index: label while using Mbmenu in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm using the Mbmenu Yii extension for the first time, and getting an error:

```
Undefined index: label
```

Can anyone, please help me to resolve this?

Here is my code that set up Mbmenu:

```
<div id="mainMbmenu">
    <?php  $this->widget('application.extensions.mbmenu.MbMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Shift 1', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>'Shift 2', 'url'=>array('/site/Shift 2')),
            array('label'=>'Shift 3', 'url'=>array('/site/Shift3')),
            array('label'=>'Prod', 'url'=>array('/prodmaster/create',)),
            'items'=>array(
                                array('label'=>'Prod'),
            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        ),
    )));
            ?>
</div><!-- mainMbmenu -->
```

Comment: can you post complete error, where you are getting (in which file)

Comment: where is the error - which line in the above?

Comment: Your inner (Prod) items must be inside another array : array('label'=>'Prod', 'items'=>array(array(''label'=>'Login', 'login'),array(''label'=>'Login', 'login')  )